# Calling a Command from a Separate Class File

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

So I have been at it for days, and for the life of me cannot find any documentation that fits my situation exactly here.

I have essentially set up a custom navigation service and would like to call the command from my ViewModel Class directly from my User Control.

I think I'm on the edge of having it here, but my lack of experience with C# is shooting me in the foot.

Here is the section of code from my Login.xaml.cs in question:

```
private LoginViewModel _loginViewModel;
        public Login(LoginViewModel loginViewModel)
        {
            _loginViewModel = loginViewModel;
        }
        private void GrantAccess()
        {
            int userAccess = Int16.Parse(User.Access);
            if (userAccess == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The bottom man");
            }
            if (userAccess == 2)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The little boss");
            }
            if (userAccess == 3)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The little big boss");
            }
            if (userAccess == 4)
            {
                {
                    _loginViewModel.NavigateMM1Command.Execute(null);
                }
            }

        }
```

and here is the command I'm trying to reference from the ViewModel:

```
public class LoginViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public ICommand NavigateMM1Command { get; }
        public LoginViewModel(NavigationStore navigationStore)
        {
            NavigateMM1Command = new NavigateCommand<MM1ViewModel>(new NavigationService<MM1ViewModel>(navigationStore, () => new MM1ViewModel(navigationStore)));
        }
    }
```

Basically I've been going through tutorial after tutorial trying to apply what they teach to what I need and its worked for the most part but now _loginViewModel is throwing a null reference exception and I'm not sure why.

I have tried:

```
LoginViewModel loginViewModel = new loginViewModel();
```

but its asking me to pass a navigationStore argument through it and that feels wrong.
Any help here will cure my temporary insanity XD

Comment: You are trying to define LoginViewModel in Login constructure, but did you add LoginViewModel as DI? Or are you using DI framework in your project?

Comment: No I haven't used any DI where should I be defining  LoginViewModel?

Comment: I can't say anything because I can't see the code. If you're not using DI, you'll have to new it.

Comment: You wrote the ctor that's expecting that parameter. You need a navigation store from somewhere. Passed in from mainwindowviewodel or a public property on app or a static or a di container... Somewhere. Whatever fits best with the rest of your app, requirements and inclination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're receiving a Null Object Reference because `navigationStore` is `null` when `LoginViewModel` is being constructed.

That is, you have not configured a means to instantiate the type `navigationStore` when constructing `LoginViewModel`.

---

Dependency Injection (DI), or Invocation of Control (IoC) is bit more comprehensive a subject to cover in this answer.

Having said that,
I'll provide code to review here.  It represents a means to configure a service provider using a collection of type mappings.

In this complete, ConsoleApp example, we'll explicitly instantiate a `ServiceCollection`, add Service Types (specifying mapping where application), and Build the `ServiceProvider`; With that provider, we'll resolve and instantiate `Login` type using `GetService` -- instantiating all the types;

The Types are essentially mockups of the types you've specified, but I've modified some aspects (an made up notioned like what your Execute method and usage of NavigationStore was).

#### DemoNavTypes

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleDemo.NavLoginDemo
{
    public interface ICommand 
    {
        void Execute(string? userName);
    }

    public interface INavigationStore {
        public bool this[string index] { get;set; }
    }

    public interface INavigationService {
        void GrantAccessToUser(string userName);
    }
    public interface INavigationViewModel { }

    internal class NavigationStore : INavigationStore
    {
        private Dictionary<string, bool> userAccessDict;

        public NavigationStore() { 
            userAccessDict = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
        }

        public bool this[string index] { 
            get => userAccessDict.TryGetValue(index, out var val) && val; 
            set => userAccessDict[index] = value; 
        }
    }

    internal class NavigationService : INavigationService
    {
        private readonly INavigationStore _navigationStore;

        public NavigationService(INavigationStore navigationStore) 
        {
            _navigationStore = navigationStore;
        }

        public void GrantAccessToUser(string? userName)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName))
                throw new ArgumentException(nameof(userName));

            _navigationStore[userName!] = true;
        }
    }

    internal class NavigationCommand : ICommand
    {
        private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;
        public NavigationCommand(INavigationService navigationService) 
        {
            _navigationService = navigationService;
        }

        public void Execute(string? userName)
        {
            if (userName != null)
            {
                _navigationService.GrantAccessToUser(userName);
            }
        }
    }

    internal class User
    {
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public string Access { get; set; } = "1";
    }

    public abstract class BaseViewModel
    {
        internal User User { get; set; } = new User();

        protected BaseViewModel() { }
    }

    internal class LoginViewModel : BaseViewModel, INavigationViewModel
    {
        private readonly ICommand _command;

        public LoginViewModel(ICommand command) : base()
        {
            _command = command;
        }

        internal ICommand NavigateMM1Command => _command;
    }

    internal class Login
    {

        private User User => _loginViewModel.User;

        private readonly LoginViewModel _loginViewModel;
        public Login(LoginViewModel loginViewModel) 
        { 
            _loginViewModel = loginViewModel;   
        }

        internal void SetAccess(int access)
        {
            SetAccess($"{access}");
        }
        internal void SetAccess(string access)
        {
            User.Access = access; 
        }

        internal void SetUserName(string userName) { User.Name = userName; }

        internal async Task GrantAccessAsync()
        {
            await Task.Yield();

            int userAccess = Int16.Parse(User.Access);
            switch (userAccess)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("The bottom man");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("The little boss");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("The little big boss");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    _loginViewModel.NavigateMM1Command.Execute(User.Name);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

#### Program.cs (using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection)

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System.Collections.Immutable;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Linq;
using ConsoleDemo.NavLoginDemo;

internal class Program
{

    private static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        var provder = ConfigureServices(services);

        var login = provder.GetService<Login>();

        if (login != null)
        {
            await login.GrantAccessAsync();
            login.SetAccess(2);
            await login.GrantAccessAsync();
            login.SetAccess(3);
            await login.GrantAccessAsync();
            login.SetUserName("James Bond");
            login.SetAccess(4);
            await login.GrantAccessAsync();
        }

    }

    private static IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        return services
            .AddScoped<INavigationStore, NavigationStore>()
            .AddScoped<INavigationService, NavigationService>()
            .AddScoped<ICommand, NavigationCommand>()
            .AddScoped<LoginViewModel>()
            .AddScoped<Login>()
            .BuildServiceProvider();
    }
}
```

#### Note

-- However,
In your application, you'll probably already have a `ServiceCollection` instance in your Program.cs or Startup.cs file. And the `ServiceProvider` (or `HostProvider`) will be managed over by the application; So, you probably won't need to explicitly resolve (or `GetService<T>`) -- just add the Service Type (mappings) in `ServiceCollection`. Those parameter types will be instantiated and 'injected' into the constructor of Type that is itself being instantiated.

Comment: Thank you very much for a thorough answer it helped me learn a lot and I spent a few hours reviewing it. I ended up creating a sperate command altogether to handle the login verification and renavigation. Can't thank you enough for pointing me in the right direction!